# Install Traminer

Tags: r, traminer

**Hi, I try to install Traminer so I write the command and this is what it appears**:

> install.packages("TraMineR")
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/TraMineR_1.8-13.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 1677684 bytes (1.6 MB)
>   downloaded 1.6 MB
>   package ‘TraMineR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   The downloaded binary packages are in
>   C:\Users\María\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUhO6sN\downloaded_packages

**Then, I write "library (Traminer)" and this is what I received**

> library(TraMineR)
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘gridExtra’
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TraMineR’

**What can I do to solve this?**
Thanks!!

Comment: maybe install gridExtra? `install.packages("gridExtra")` - don't know why installing TraMiner didn't pull this in but you've not really given us many details...

Comment: TraMineR won't pull that in because it does not make use of gridExtra. There is no reference to gridExtra in its namespace,

Comment: @Gilbert Correct - but Hmisc is imported and Hmisc imports gridExtra. So indirectly gridExtra is required to be installed.